# Cakephp about query is it possible?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I have a question about cakephp about there $this->query is it possible to combine three query and make it one,?example like this

```
$this->Training->query(Select sample.* from sample where sample.name like "me")
$this->Training->query(Select sample2.* from sample2 where sample2.name like "you")
$this->Training->query(Select sample3.* from sample3 where sample3.name like "us")
```

this is a search function combination,2 selectbox and 1 textbox

Comment: You could possibly use joins?

Comment: but I dont yet know about the join in cakephp,im new in this framework,so im using the query of php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use UNION clause,

```
$this->Training->query(Select sample.* from sample where sample.name like "me"
                 UNION Select sample2.* from sample2 where sample2.name like "you"
                 UNION Select sample3.* from sample3 where sample3.name like "us")
```

Comment: Although this does answer the question, this is not how you should be using CakePHP. In fact, it gives a ready-to-use search function (in this case, `$this->Training->find()`, and you should leave `query()` only when it doesn't fit your needs. Please look at this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find